# Spring Kafka's MessageListener still consuming after MessageListenerContainer is stopped

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-kafka

My goal is to create my own Camel component for Spring Kafka.

I have managed to create it and start consuming. I also want to be able to stop the component and consumption (with JMX, with other Camel route,...), without loosing any messages.
To do that, when stopping Camel component, I need to stop a `MessageListenerContainer` and eventually `MessageListener` which is registered in `MessageListenerContainer`.

My problem is that when `MessageListenerContainer` is stopped, `MessageListener` is still processing messages.

```
    @Override
    protected void doStart() throws Exception {
        super.doStart();
        if (kafkaMessageListenerContainer != null) {
            return;
        }

        kafkaMessageListenerContainer = kafkaListenerContainerFactory.createContainer(endpoint.getTopicName());
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.setupMessageListener(messageListener());
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doStop() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("STOPPING kafkaMessageListenerContainer");
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.stop();
        LOG.info("STOPPED kafkaMessageListenerContainer");
        super.doStop();
    }

    private MessageListener<Object, Object> messageListener() {
        return new MessageListener<Object, Object>() {
            @Override public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> data) {
                LOG.info("Record received: {}", data.offset());
                //...pass a message to Camel processing route
                LOG.info("Record processed: {}", data.offset());
            }
        };
    }
```

This is snippet from log

```
{"time":"2020-11-27T14:01:57.047Z","message":"Record received: 2051","logger":"com.my.lib.springboot.camel.component.kafka.KafkaAdapterConsumer","thread-id":"consumer-0-C-1","level":"INFO","tId":"c5efc5db-5981-4477-925a-83ffece49572"}
{"time":"2020-11-27T14:01:57.153Z","message":"STOPPED kafkaMessageListenerContainer","logger":"com.my.lib.springboot.camel.component.kafka.KafkaAdapterConsumer","thread-id":"Camel (camelContext) thread #2 - ShutdownTask","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2020-11-27T14:01:57.153Z","message":"Route: testTopic.consumer shutdown complete, was consuming from: my-kafka://events.TestTopic","logger":"org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy","thread-id":"Camel (camelContext) thread #2 - ShutdownTask","level":"INFO"}
{"time":"2020-11-27T14:01:57.159Z","message":"Record processed: 2051","logger":"com.my.lib.springboot.camel.component.kafka.KafkaAdapterConsumer","thread-id":"consumer-0-C-1","level":"INFO","tId":"8c835691-ba8d-43c2-b3e0-90a2f768ed7f"}
{"time":"2020-11-27T14:01:57.165Z","message":"Record received: 2052","logger":"com.my.lib.springboot.camel.component.kafka.KafkaAdapterConsumer","thread-id":"consumer-0-C-1","level":"INFO","tId":"8c835691-ba8d-43c2-b3e0-90a2f768ed7f"}
{"time":"2020-11-27T14:01:57.275Z","message":"Record processed: 2052","logger":"com.my.lib.springboot.camel.component.kafka.KafkaAdapterConsumer","thread-id":"consumer-0-C-1","level":"INFO","tId":"f7bcebb4-9e5e-46a1-bc5b-569264914b05"}
...
```

I would expect that `MessageListener` would not consume anymore after `MessageListenerContainer` is gracefully stopped. I must be missing something, any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a issue which caused my problem.

For some reason I was overriding consumerFactory which was not correct.

```
        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, localhost:9092);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer);
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
        }
```

After removing this and use default one, which is configured in application.yml, problem was resolved.